# How can I hide the taskbar in Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, taskbar

I am currently making a deployment program in VB.net and I am having trouble hiding the taskbar. My code works in Windows 7, but it does not seem to work after the Windows 10 upgrade.

Here is my code:

```
Imports system.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Partial Class MainForm
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer
Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer

Public Const SWP_HIDEWINDOW = &H80
Public Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
```

And to hide it, I do:

```
Dim intReturn As Integer = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "")
SetWindowPos(intReturn, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_HIDEWINDOW)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is that you're using deprecated function declarations. I tested your code with the proper declarations for [`FindWindow`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html) and [`SetWindowPos`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos.html) and everything is working fine (Windows 10 x64).

Here's my code for reference:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As SetWindowPosFlags) As Boolean
    End Function

    <Flags>
    Private Enum SetWindowPosFlags As UInteger
        SynchronousWindowPosition = &H4000
        DeferErase = &H2000
        DrawFrame = &H20
        FrameChanged = &H20
        HideWindow = &H80
        DoNotActivate = &H10
        DoNotCopyBits = &H100
        IgnoreMove = &H2
        DoNotChangeOwnerZOrder = &H200
        DoNotRedraw = &H8
        DoNotReposition = &H200
        DoNotSendChangingEvent = &H400
        IgnoreResize = &H1
        IgnoreZOrder = &H4
        ShowWindow = &H40
    End Enum

    Sub Main()
        Dim window As IntPtr = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "")
        SetWindowPos(window, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.HideWindow)
    End Sub
End Module
```