# Vb.net Hide Task bar in Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, 64-bit, windows-10

I found this sample code from another question but I don't know how to run this code. When I paste this into my project I have no errors but when I run the code it never breaks into this code.

[How can I hide the taskbar in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172249/how-can-i-hide-the-taskbar-in-windows-10#new-answer)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As SetWindowPosFlags) As Boolean
    End Function

    <Flags>
  Private Enum SetWindowPosFlags As UInteger
    SynchronousWindowPosition = &H4000
    DeferErase = &H2000
    DrawFrame = &H20
    FrameChanged = &H20
    HideWindow = &H80
    DoNotActivate = &H10
    DoNotCopyBits = &H100
    IgnoreMove = &H2
    DoNotChangeOwnerZOrder = &H200
    DoNotRedraw = &H8
    DoNotReposition = &H200
    DoNotSendChangingEvent = &H400
    IgnoreResize = &H1
    IgnoreZOrder = &H4
    ShowWindow = &H40
  End Enum

  Sub Main()
    Dim window As IntPtr = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "")
    SetWindowPos(window, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.HideWindow)
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `SetWindowPos(window, ...)` line and verify that `window` is not zero. You might also want to apply the `IgnoreMove` and `IgnoreResize` flags too so that the task bar isn't resized or moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

I tried your code and added Debug info in a console, it works fine for me :

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Finding the Window")
    Dim window As IntPtr = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "")
    Console.WriteLine("Window handle : " & window.ToString() & " - press a key to hide the taskbar")
    Console.ReadKey()
    SetWindowPos(window, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.HideWindow)
    Console.WriteLine("Window has been hidden, press a key to show it.")
    Console.ReadKey()
    SetWindowPos(window, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.ShowWindow)
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to end program")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Made using Visual Studio 2012 Express on Windows 10 64 Bits