# Hide and Show taskbar on windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, interop, taskbar

I have a wpf application which is in maximized state always without showing taskbar. 
Here is the code for Hiding and showing taskbar.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

    static int hwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");

    public static new void Hide()
    {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);    
    }
    public static new void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
```

This is working fine on windows 7. But when application runs on Windows 10.. taskbar didnt show up again by calling show().

Here is the part where I am calling show()

```
  #region Show Desktop
    private void Desktop_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left )
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
            Shell32.Shell objShel = new Shell32.Shell();              
            objShel.MinimizeAll();
            Show();
        }

    }

#endregion
```

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the `MinimizeAll()` call. I can't reproduce it (never used `Shell32`)...without that code, it works totally fine for me on Win10. Is it possible that the `MinimizeAll()` call "minimizes" the taskbar? I can't test because `MinimizeAll()` throws an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172249/how-can-i-hide-the-taskbar-in-windows-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on the main display and is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172249/how-can-i-hide-the-taskbar-in-windows-10) and converted to c#.

```
public static class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(
        string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetWindowPos(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
        int x,
        int y,
        int cx,
        int cy,
        uint uFlags
    );

    [Flags]
    private enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
    {
        HideWindow = 128,
        ShowWindow = 64
    }

    public static void Show()
    {
        var window = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "");
        SetWindowPos(window, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (uint) SetWindowPosFlags.ShowWindow);
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        var window = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "");
        SetWindowPos(window, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (uint)SetWindowPosFlags.HideWindow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I will try this first

Comment: No problem, if the answer was helpful, mark it as answer, thanks :)

Comment: I am sorry for replying this late... But it still is not working on windows 10

Comment: It's working on windows 10 for me. How can we do the same on the other displays ?